# Appropriate use of "nascent" on chatroom FAQ page

Tags: feature-request, chat

On the [chat.stackoverflow.com/faq](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#irc) page, under the *Why don't you guys just use IRC, man?* section, the IRC client is described as "nascent":

> We're trying to build a system better and easier to use than IRC, that is native to modern web browsers. Will we support [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)? [We're not sure yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat). In the meantime, there is a [**nascent** community project](http://github.com/ghewgill/soirc) to create an IRC interface to our chat.

The [last commit](https://github.com/ghewgill/soirc) was almost 5 years ago! I think it's hardly appropriate to continue to call it nascent.

Definition from the OED:

> (especially of a process or organization) just coming into existence and beginning to display signs of future potential: *the nascent space industry.*

Can this adjective be fixed?

Comment: Would you prefer "unsupported", "antiquated" or "unofficial"?  The code hasn't been touched for five years...

Comment: @Makoto is "all of the above" an option? (edit: the foremost and lattermost are a little too similar to be included together tbh)

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Sure ain't a new thing anymore.

Comment: should it go straight to "senescent"?

Comment: @cphlewis I added that to the list below

Comment: Also 6 commits by one person is hardly a "community project".

Comment: Not at all surprising that yet another chat system has failed to interface with IRC. This idea of conquering IRC seems to come to every nascent programmer at some point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The project is clearly dead.

Let's simply remove the reference entirely; it serves no purpose.

Comment: @hakre: It _barely_ works. It was reasonable when the term "nascent" applied because investing in the project made sense. But, as it stands now, it's barely useful to anyone, _and_ that's apparently not going to change. I don't see the benefit in prominently linking to a dead project whose binary can let you do 40% of chat things in a single chat room. Let's just snip it out. **Less is more.** _"There is no need to remove it."_ Having no text should be the default, with text only there _if it is of actual benefit to someone_. If someone _really_ wants to find the project then they still can.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: :)

Comment: So if I mark this accepted, how do we know whether it ever gets done?

Comment: @royhowie: Marking it as accepted has nothing to do with it. If you care about this question and would like to see when an answer is posted then, like any other webpage in which you are interested, you shall add it to your browser's "Favourites" or "Bookmarks" (just like we have done since 1992) and check up on it when you wish to see whether there is an update. If you would like any further information don't hesitate to comment back and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I wasn't alive in 1992 :(

Comment: @royhowie: :/​​ Does this prevent you from using the "Favourites"/"Bookmarks" feature, though? Really?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a list of possible replacement words. Feel free to edit in any others (keep alphabetical).

- antediluvian
- antiquated
- bygone
- démodé
- inadequate
- incomplete
- insufficient
- obsolete
- old
- out-of-date
- outdated
- outmoded
- passé
- senescent
- unofficial
- unsupported

Comment: Why mention the project _at all_ if these are the words we can use to describe it?

Comment: Isn't 'still-born' the appropriate term?

Comment: If we want to get less creative, the proper term would probably be DOA, though that's mostly used as a critique.